# Trying to use 5 registers in Xilinx's AXI Lite interface

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, zynq

I have an IP for Digilent's Zybo Z7-20 which segments the image. The segmentation is done based on histogram. The segmentation module takes 4 32-bit wide inputs which contain the threshold values. In addition the module takes one input which represents the enable. My problem is that when I had only 3 thresholds (R, G, B), the module worked, but when I add the thresholds for channel A, it stops working. So it accepted 4 registers but not 5.

---

I get this error message

> [Synth 8-97] array index 4 out of range ["c:/Users/suvi1/Documents/icat3170/segmente_modified/vivado_proj/Zybo-Z7-20-DMA.srcs/sources_1/bd/system/ipshared/073f/hdl/segmenter_modified_v1_0_S00_AXI.vhd":232]

The row 232 reads as follows:

`loc_addr := axi_awaddr(ADDR_LSB + OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto ADDR_LSB);`

The signal axi_awaddr is defined earlier as

```
signal axi_awaddr    : std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

and

```
    C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH    : integer    := 5
```

How can I get "array index 4 out of range" when the size of the vector is 5?!

Other variables used on that row are defined:

```
constant ADDR_LSB  : integer := (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/32)+ 1;
C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH    : integer    := 32;
constant OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS : integer := 2;
```

---

If you want to test it, here are the files.

My IP repo:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gqp0hoc0ws8lqp/new_ip_repo.zip?dl=0
From there I use segmenter_modified.

The Xilinx Vivado project which uses the abovementioned IP segmenter_modified.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s51skutnj9a74i8/segm_mod.zip?dl=0

Instructions:

1. Download the zip packages and unzip them.
2. Open the Vivado project of the second link. Project name is Zybo-Z7-20-DMA.
3. (*I'm not sure if this is needed* : Make sure the IP Catalog contains the path to where you downloaded and unzipped the IP repo, in my case it's C:\Users\suvi1\Downloads\new_ip_repo\new_ip_repo\ip_repo)
4. Try to generate the bitstream and you see the errors.

Comment: The Vivado project in dropbox `vivado_proj/Zybo-Z7-20-DMA.srcs/sources_1/bd/system/ipshared/` doesn't contain a folder `073f` so it seems there is some version confusion. Maybe what you're compiling isn't what you think you're compiling, and the error message refers to a version where 4 is indeed out of range. OR since one of these values is a GENERIC, what value has it been instantiated with?

Comment: What is `073f`? I checked the GENERIC instantiation, it was indeed 4. I fixed it but it did not help.

Comment: It's in the error message you posted; in the path to the file that's actually being compiled. I could trace from vivado_proj as far as ipshared, but no further.

Comment: I created another IP from scratch, and copied the correct codes there. No help.

Comment: So, follow the new path in the new error message, and inspect the actually compiled file. Also, add ASSERT/REPORTs on the relevant constants, generics, and array index attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There were 4's in two places where there should have been 5.

In file `segmenter_modified_v1_0` I had to change the row 15 to

```
    C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH    : integer   := 5;
```

and the row 80 to

```
    C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  : integer   := 5;
```